# How can i get dragged item data in metarial drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm learning angular. My first application is todolist. I'm trying to develop it by using nodejs and mongodb. There are three container such as todos doings and dones. When i drag an item from todos to doings i want to handle it's id. How can i do that ?

```
      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                            event.container.data,
                            event.previousIndex,
                            event.currentIndex);
        }

              ///TODO handle dragged item id,title or someinformation


      }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass data to a drag-gable item like this:

```
<div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="todo" *ngFor="let todo of todos"></div>
```

The data, in this case your todo item will be available in the event object.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  console.log(event.item.data);
}
```

Comment: That's what i've been looking for hours.Thanks

Comment: its not working for me its said undefined
this is what I get after event.item
CdkDrag {element: ElementRef, dropContainer: CdkDropList, 
_document: document, _ngZone: NgZone, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef_, …}
nothing in data

Comment: another way for it 
event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]